# Simple Interest to Compound Interest

Tags: loans, banking, calculation

In simple annual interest terms 60/2000 is 3%. But what is the rate if this is the total interest paid on 2000 after monthly compounding over 3 years?

Answer (score 3):

Annualising the 3% three year simple interest by taking the cube root.

```
Annual effective rate = (1 + 0.03)^(1/3) - 1 = 0.00990163 = 0.99 %
```

**Alternatively**

Using the following formula:

http://www.financeformulas.net/Compound_Interest.html

[image]

```
60 = 2000 ((1 + r)^36 - 1)

∴ monthly rate, r = 0.000821415

annual nominal rate = 12 r = 0.00985698 = 0.99 % compounded monthly

and annual effective rate = (1 + r)^12 - 1 = 0.00990163 = 0.99 %
```

***Check***

Compounding with the [annual effective rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation) over three years yields the correct interest.

```
2000 ((1 + 0.00990163)^3 - 1) = 60
```

Answer (score 2):

0.99% is the annual rate of interest (assuming a constant rate throughout the three years) that would result in that return with compounding.

Answer (score 0):

Monthly compounding over three years is compounding over 36 periods. An annual rate of three percent breaks down to 0.25% per month. So now apply the RIP formula:

R = I ^ P

Return is the interest ratio (Intrest rate divided by 100 then added to one) raised to the power of the number of periods.

I is 1.0025. P is 36. R = 1.0025^36.

R = 1.09405140077

So you get a little bit better than 9% over three years.

Edit:The formula is reversible:

I = R ^ (1/P)

P = log(R) / log(I)

Edit2: Please leave a comment as to why you voted negatively.

Edit3: @Chris -  nope, the third word in the OP is 'annual',  meaning he gets his 3% in ONE year. He is asking what the total return would be if he let compounding work for another two years.

Edit4: If you are asking what the annual rate is if your Total Return in three years is $2060.00 is on an initial investment  of $2000 then the I = R ^ (1/P) applies.

60 / 2000 gets you a ratio of 0.03. Add 1 for 1.03. 1.03 ^ (1/3) gets you 1.00990163405.  Subtract 1,and multiply by 100 for an annual percentage rate of 0.9902%

Comment: The OP says the 3% is over three years, so `I = R^(1/P) = 1.03^(1/36) = 1.000821415`.  (Not my downvote by the way.)

Comment: Re. Edit 3 - I'm sure he's asking "*what is the rate if this*" i.e. 60 "*is the total interest paid on 2000 after monthly compounding over 3 years?*"